# Google Maps API v3 Custom Button moving around

Tags: javascript, google-maps

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dale12/uowhmfh5/) reproducing the issue.

I am adding a custom button to the top center of the map.  I have a click event attached to the map that will fadeIn the button.  A rightclick event on the map that will fadeOut the button.

To reproduce the issue:

1. Right click on the map to fadeOut the button.
2. Increase/decrease zoom level by at least one level.
3. Left click to fadeIn the button.

At this point the button will fade back in at a location different
than its original location.

4. Increase/decrease zoom level by at least one level.

You will then see the button snap back to its original location.

```js
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.508742, -0.120850),
    zoom: 7,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

  var btn = document.getElementById('myButton');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(btn);

  map.addListener('click', function() {
    jQuery('#myButton').fadeIn();
  });

  map.addListener('rightclick', function() {
    jQuery('#myButton').fadeOut();
  });
```

```css
.button {
  display: block;
}

#map {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button class="button" id="myButton">asdf</button>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see your issue in the posted code snippet.  The button is either hidden, or visible at the top center.  Changing the zoom level (by clicking on the map) doesn't change the position (although it does hide/show the button)

Comment: I should have added, I"m testing this in Chrome.  Did you test it in the JSFiddle ?  Were you not able to reproduce the issue following the steps I laid out ?
Please provide feedback for the down vote so I can address your concerns.  This is an easily reproducible issue I'm experiencing and I've laid it out in great detail.

Comment: That looks like a potential bug with the control positions on the `Map` object. As a workaround, you could try removing the button on the rightclick from the `Map` controls (with a slight timeout to let the fadeout effect complete), then readding it back to the map on the left click. [Simple sample JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wexaletabe/edit?html,output)

Comment: @Preston  Thank you.  That's exactly the type of thing I was looking for.  Feel free to post your work around as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a potential bug with the control positions on the `Map` object. You may want to [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207) on Google's Public Issue Tracker.

As a workaround, you could try removing the button on the `rightclick` from the `Map` controls (with a slight timeout to let the fadeout effect complete), then readding it back to the map on the left `click`.

[Simple sample JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wexaletabe/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps Custom Controls</title>
    <style>
    .button {
      display: block;
      width: 70px;
    }

    #map {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=YOUR_KEY" async defer></script>
    <script>
    function initMap() {
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.508742, -0.120850),
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    zoom: 7,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

  var btn = document.getElementById('myButton');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(btn);

  map.addListener('click', function() {
      if (!jQuery('#myButton').is(":visible")) {
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(btn);
        jQuery('#myButton').fadeIn();
      }
  });

  map.addListener('rightclick', function() {
      if (jQuery('#myButton').is(":visible")) {
          jQuery('#myButton').fadeOut();
          setTimeout(function(){ map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].pop(btn); }, 500)
      }
  });
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button class="button" id="myButton">asdf</button>
  </body>
</html>
```